# Is there an application like "Allmyapps" for developers?

Tags: .net, silverlight

Allmyaps works pretty well for a lot of programs.  I'd like to find something similar that will install service packs for things like Visual Studio, silverlight etc.

Setting up new development machines is a pain in the neck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you create a [custom installation image](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637993(v=ws.10).aspx)?

Comment: Not really viable.  I'd like to be able "share" a profile so many developers can use it to get the base apps installed.  Nothing irks me more when I have to sit at someone else's machine and they have crap utilities installed, not to mention they dont have the latest SP's

Comment: I suggest taking your question to serverfault, which is more about IT-level stuff.  I've voted in that direction.